# How to integrate reCaptcha to a Spring boot based Java application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I need to implement a silent (invisible) reCaptcha in order to prevent bot attacks, etc. So, user does not enter data as like in standard reCaptcha. Instead, an invisible reCaptcha will be integrated to my Spring Boot application at the backend side.

So, how can I integrate such a mechanism to the project (Spring Boot app)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does anyone else has ever used Invisible reCaptcha in Java?

Comment: @Editor Any help besides edit request?

Answer (score 0):

first if you want a throttle mechanism per IP etc, this is not a captcha,
this is what you are looking for:

[spring-security-block-brute-force](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-block-brute-force-authentication-attempts)

recaptcha is by definition a way to stop bots from abusing the website frontend to affect the backend,

[recaptcha definition by google](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/)

for this I would recommend google recaptcha v3, it is completely silent(other than the small logo on the website), there is no images with select the car etc... the way it works is by collecting behavioral data from the user on the page(great for single page apps like react),

In the backend you store your site private key in advance (pub & private keys are provided by google per domain name)

after user send the login/register or any other request you can send the user captcha token with it,

then you can give the token to google and get a score for said user(between 0-1, the higher the better) you also get the captcha action to make sure action is in correlation with api called, this is all in spring not in the frontend, from there you can decide to stop the registration/ login process before even accessing the DB to get user data & as a result stop the bot attempts quickly...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanations. I registered on Google and obtained necessary key, etc. However, I need an example backend implementation for Java and then I will test it by Postman. Could you please add an example backend code for Java in addition to your good explanations?

Comment: By the way, I tried to vote up but as I have not enough repo, I cannot. I will mark as answer after I make it work.

Comment: @hexadecimal you cannot test it with postman, again this is a specific feature for UI & BE integration,
here is a testing guide:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-registration-captcha

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I had an implementation for frontend but I am not sure if I can also use it with the integration mentioned on that page you gave (v3). At least, does that page contains all the necessary frontend and backend implementation for integration of Captcha v3? Actually I need to integrate it to an **Vue** app, and not sure if I have to change something extra?

Comment: On the other hand, its explanations is really bad with lack of information. Any better example for Captcha v3?